# Surprising warning in integrate (R), "longer object length not a multiple of shorter"

Tags: r, debugging, warnings

I reproduce a warning I get in `integrate` in `R`.

```
r <- list()
r$t <- 1:4
xsq <- function(x,r_obj){
  r_obj$t == x
  return(x^2)
}
integrate(f=xsq,0,1, r_obj = r)
```

The fourth line has no function in this toy example (that I constructed from a more complex function in which the line is needed). The problem is that the code above gives a warning related to this line:

```
0.3333333 with absolute error < 3.7e-15
Warning message:
In r_obj$t == x :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Note that evaluating `xsq` at any value is not problematic, e.g. `xsq(1, r_obj = r)` does not give any warning. Also when `r$t` has less than 4 elements, e.g. `r$t <- 1:3`, the problem disappears. However, from `?integrate` `f` is

> An R function taking a numeric first argument and returning a numeric vector of the same length.

In my understanding `xsq` does just that. Where do I go wrong or why do I get a warning?

Comment: What is `r_obj$t == x` even supposed to accomplish? You don't assign it to anything. Why run that line at all?

Comment: @joran It is part of a more complex function that I need to integrate. In the above toy example it does not have any meaning, but reproduces the warning. I'll make an edit to clarify this

Comment: In doing it's work, `integrate` is going to evaluate `xsq` for vectors that may  not be of length 1 or 4, hence the warning.

Comment: @joran so it is basically checking on the first run how long the vector passef to `f` needs to be?

Comment: I don't understand that comment. Basically all numerical integration involves evaluating the function at many points over an interval. Your function is basically assuming that that number of points will always be a multiple of 4, which hardly seems a reasonable expectation.

Comment: @joran my function is 1 to 1. The function `r_obj$t == x` is 1 to 4. I did not understand why this should give a warning. But I believe you are saying that `integrate` assumes that `f` is vectorized, i.e. it may pass as many values as desired? Is this correct? Then I understand the warning.

Comment: Yes. In order to do numerical integration, it has to evaluate `xsq` at possibly many, many points in a vectorized fashion.

Comment: @joran thanks. this answers my question but does not solve my actual problem on how to integrate my (non-vectorized) 1 on 1 function.